# How to create a translucent <TextInput/> in React Native?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to create a translucent `<TextInput/>` exactly like shown below in React Native? If so, any guidance or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: what's the question? is it possible? -> yes. "guidance" is hard to answer correctly.. Please include some code with what you've tried already

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply some styles such as opacity and border radius, it's pretty simple actually:

```
textfield: {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)',
  borderRadius: 5,
  width: 250,
  height: 40,
  padding: 5,
}
```

Here's a working example: https://rnplay.org/apps/I-jDRg

Good luck!

Comment: Appreciate it, Looks pretty much the same! Before I accept the question, how would I get the text input to start further away from the border like in the example? Because in the sample you provided, the text starts extremely close the border. Also, how can I change the blinking text cursor to that particular grey color? And lastly, how can I make it so that it dynamically resizes depending on the device size? Thanks Crysfel!

Comment: please let me know if you've seen my last comment. thank you

Comment: Please read the docs, everything is documented there and it's really easy to accomplish ;) good luck!

Comment: Still no luck. Could you show so I can accept the answer?

Comment: Try using `placeholderTextColor` to change the color of the placeholder